# Are passives like "it was decided / planned to do" correct?

Tags: passive-voice, impersonal-passive

Such structures seem wrong to me but I've come across such usage in "The Cyberiad" by Stanisław Lem, excellently translated from Polish by Michael Kandel.

*... it was decided to withhold the payment...*

I would change it to:

*it was decided that the payment should be withheld*

Since there is no subject in the original sentence, I feel an infinitive cannot be used, in contrast to:

*He deciced to withhold the payment*

Therefore, an impersonal clause like "it was decided" can only be followed by a clause with a subject. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: The concept of "correct" doesn't apply here. Passive voice is just another tool in a writer's kit. Overuse may cause prose to sound affected, but there is nothing wrong with it per se.

Comment: **It was decided to** and **it was decided that** are pretty much neck-and-neck nowadays.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+was+decided+to%2Cit+was+decided+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @TimR, I don't think that the focus of the question is so much on the choice between *that* and *to* as on whether the passive form of 'it was decided' calls for the passive in what follows ('the payment should be withheld').

Comment: @jsw29 That is not how I understood "I feel an infinitive cannot be used"

Comment: I'd say the construction has a very narrow range of verb combos that work well, and this isn't one of them. *It was rumored to run on hydrogen* works okay. *It was insisted to run on hydrogen* doesn't, and *it was decided to run on hydrogen* might work in some situations. But I would be inclined to insert a subject noun. Note that the first example with *rumor* is about an attribute of *it*, while the others are about some relationship with *it*.

Comment: @Phil Sweet 'It was decided [by X] to withhold the payment' = 'X decided to withhold the payment'. This paraphrase isn't available for 'It was rumoured to run on hydrogen', even though this is quite correct. Contrast 'It was found to run on hydrogen' I think there are subtleties here. 'It was voted/chosen to refer this to the management' are fine, but not with 'opted'. I agree about the narrow range of (semantically appropriate candidates only) verb combos possible. // Answers need to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly they’re “correct”, given [how commonplace their occurrence in published English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+was+planned+to%2C+it+was+decided+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3):

[image: ngram of it was decided/planned to]

That’s the only measure of “correct” that matters here.

One quibble, though. This sentence:

- It was decided to withhold the payment.

does indeed possess a grammatical subject: that subject is *it*, which is why the verb *was* agrees with it in number. English lacks any grammatical rule that demands that sentence be written as the ponderously heavy:

- It was decided that the payment **be withheld**.

That’s not incorrect but it’s heavy-handed, perhaps even super-formal, and not often heard.

Because what was decided requires no change in subject, there’s no reason to use a finite subordinate clause beginning with *that* as the asker suggested be used. It can even sound overly formal and heavy handed done that way. Compare the first two with infinitives to the ones with *that* clauses:

- It was important **to** leave early.
- It was decided **to** leave early.
- It was decided **that** everyone leave early.
- It was decided **that** everyone shall leave early.
- It was decided **that** everyone should leave early.
- It was decided **that** everyone must leave early.

The second set is a lot heavier, and it forces the introduction of a subject that may not be appropriate. Even so, another possibility exists:

- It was decided **for** everyone **to** leave early.
- It was important **for** everyone **to** leave early.
- It was critical **for** everyone **to** leave early.

Here follow many examples of those three common patterns I just gave, as documented by Google Books, and presented here in decreasing order of frequency.

## 1. It was decided *to* INF-VERB

The most common collocation following *it was decided* is indeed with *to*:

- [It was decided to sell the previous purchased lot and buy lots on the south side of town from Mr. J. Wiggins](https://books.google.com/books?id=KBNVAwAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PA1954&dq=%22it+was+decided+to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii1oP_77WEAxWJBTQIHblvCoUQ6AF6BAgHEAI).
- [It was decided to repair it no matter how long this took.](https://books.google.com/books?id=uyFiAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA150&dq=%22it+was+decided+to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii1oP_77WEAxWJBTQIHblvCoUQ6AF6BAgGEAI)
- [It was decided not to intervene in Iraq as such as operation was considered too risky. ... On the one hand, it was decided to seek limited accommodation with him. On the other, it was felt necessary to continue support for Qasim in Iraq, who had become dangerously dependent on communist support, because he opposed Nasser.](https://books.google.com/books?id=EU2RAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA281&dq=%22it+was+decided+to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOvqe08bWEAxX-EDQIHf4ZCPU4FBDoAXoECAsQAg)
- [It was decided to authorize the Council to forward the memorandum.](https://books.google.com/books?id=kpGXtKINVy4C&pg=PA376&dq=%22it+was+decided+to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii1oP_77WEAxWJBTQIHblvCoUQ6AF6BAgEEAI)
- [It was decided to agree to the proposed emergency settlement of panel practitioners’ accounts for 1915](https://books.google.com/books?id=JTxHAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA2-PA34&dq=%22it+was+decided+to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizjtPQ67WEAxUOHjQIHY0hCNEQ6AF6BAgGEAI).
- [It was decided to ask the county council to provide a horsed fire-escape at the Tooley-street station, and to suggest to the Fire Brigade Committee the desirability of a fire station being built on some of the land...](https://books.google.com/books?id=FSI-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA722&dq=%22it+was+decided+to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizjtPQ67WEAxUOHjQIHY0hCNEQ6AF6BAgFEAI)
- [It was decided to concentrate the whole data collection on industrial companies.](https://books.google.com/books?id=_6U7GDka5iEC&pg=PA214&dq=%22it+was+decided+to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1lKqH8bWEAxWOMjQIHTEwCu44ChDoAXoECAQQAg)
- [It was decided to wait for two hours, hoping the vessel would leave the area by 2200, the latest they could launch the Zodiacs.](https://books.google.com/books?id=_FbdCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA224&dq=%22it+was+decided+to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1lKqH8bWEAxWOMjQIHTEwCu44ChDoAXoECAsQAg)
- [It was decided to turn on the reactor only when Pluto was over the Pacific Ocean, after the rockets had fallen away in a launch.](https://books.google.com/books?id=dWmLEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA122&dq=%22it+was+decided+to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOvqe08bWEAxX-EDQIHf4ZCPU4FBDoAXoECA0QAg)

## 2. It was decided *that* SUBJ VERB

The collocation with *that* is almost only ever used for an explicit change in subject:

- [It was decided that it was not advisable at this time to re-district the continent but to assign to certain vice-presidents associations which they could best serve until the district lines can be rearranged.](https://books.google.com/books?id=4HrnAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA265&dq=%22it+was+decided+that%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0g9rQ67WEAxUnDzQIHX3nDW4Q6AF6BAgFEAI)
- [It was decided that he was no longer entitled to incapacity benefit.](https://books.google.com/books?id=LZVLFd3Cn_wC&pg=PA675&dq=%22it+was+decided+that%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV57KR9bWEAxU7HTQIHTxLBMg4HhDoAXoECAYQAg)
- [It was decided that it meant the same thing as “delivered in execution,” and therefore that difficulty vanished.](https://books.google.com/books?id=UXUyAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA110&dq=%22it+was+decided+that%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0g9rQ67WEAxUnDzQIHX3nDW4Q6AF6BAgMEAI)
- [It was decided that the canteen needed longer hours and more staff.](https://books.google.com/books?id=AxZnKfM90nEC&pg=PA107&dq=%22it+was+decided+that%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-uIr487WEAxW4HzQIHb2mCIEQ6AF6BAgFEAI)
- [It was decided that an investigative topic be developed for the bottom curriculum students.](https://books.google.com/books?id=RX0fEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA89&dq=%22it+was+decided+that%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv1eK_9LWEAxXUADQIHcgBCR84ChDoAXoECAUQAg)
- [It was decided that Local No. 69 be instructed to take these men into their membership and upon refusal to do so, their charter be revoked.](https://books.google.com/books?id=5ToAAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA4-PA337&dq=%22it+was+decided+that%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0g9rQ67WEAxUnDzQIHX3nDW4Q6AF6BAgEEAI)
- [It was decided that liquid metal in pig casting shall be taken directly from the tapping crucibles instead of metal transfer vehicle.](https://books.google.com/books?id=H8QiAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22it+was+decided+that%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv1eK_9LWEAxXUADQIHcgBCR84ChDoAXoECAgQAg)
- [It was decided that the area covered by the Guildford and Reigate District Insurance Committees and the Epsom and Godstone Rural District Councils should be the areas to which this fund should apply.](https://books.google.com/books?id=RZNMAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA348&dq=%22it+was+decided+that%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0g9rQ67WEAxUnDzQIHX3nDW4Q6AF6BAgHEAI)
- [It was decided that an inter-governmental conference on EMU should be held in 1990.](https://books.google.com/books?id=vKHzBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA204&dq=%22it+was+decided+that%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv1eK_9LWEAxXUADQIHcgBCR84ChDoAXoECAwQAg)
- [It was decided that Stauffenberg must go through with his next attempt whatever the circumstances.](https://books.google.com/books?id=cR0rAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT213&dq=%22it+was+decided+that%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-uIr487WEAxW4HzQIHb2mCIEQ6AF6BAgMEAI)

Please notice that some of those clauses at the start of the set of examples take real pasts in the *that* clause, whereas those near the bottom take “unreal” (modal) clauses.

## 3. It was decided *for* SUBJ *to* INF-VERB

A more recent collocation is with *for*, followed by an infinitive clause with an explicit subject:

- [It was decided for Voyager to go to a digital computer-based attitude control system.](https://books.google.com/books?id=E-NGFqfq1LsC&pg=PA148&dq=%22it+was+decided+for%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCn4n27LWEAxWlMDQIHfZ9A0Q4ChDoAXoECAoQAg)
- [It was decided for each ISS unit to introduce four levels of reporting.](https://books.google.com/books?id=kuSQAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA305&dq=%22it+was+decided+for%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPzozV7LWEAxVOODQIHTzfBI8Q6AF6BAgKEAI)
- [It was decided for it to have its own new category.](https://books.google.com/books?id=2JU_CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT129&dq=%22it+was+decided+for%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPzozV7LWEAxVOODQIHTzfBI8Q6AF6BAgLEAI)
- [It was decided for June to be admitted to a care home.](https://books.google.com/books?id=XVZgDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT76&dq=%22it+was+decided+for%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix1bqV7bWEAxWOweYEHfSUCX04FBDoAXoECAsQAg)
- [It was decided for Eurojust to come to The Hague](https://books.google.com/books?id=cVDR3TLF2aEC&pg=RA1-PA119&dq=%22it+was+decided+for%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFko7n9rWEAxWbGDQIHf9KCYU4HhDoAXoECAQQAg).
- [It was decided for the Police to proceed with the execution of writs...](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZCsz8_oqL94C&q=%22it+was+decided+for%22&dq=%22it+was+decided+for%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRjpmB97WEAxU1ITQIHZrPA8g4KBDoAXoECAsQAg)
- [It was decided for us to take back the prisoners, and the other boats to endeavour to take in the submarine.](https://books.google.com/books?id=vB9jo1pm8UEC&pg=PT111&dq=%22it+was+decided+for%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRjpmB97WEAxU1ITQIHZrPA8g4KBDoAXoECA0QAg)
- [It was decided for the pilot to start with a safety theme that would incorporate a number of different messages that have been developed and presented in schools by park staff.](https://books.google.com/books?id=XdssAQAAMAAJ&q=%22it+was+decided+for%22&dq=%22it+was+decided+for%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRjpmB97WEAxU1ITQIHZrPA8g4KBDoAXoECAUQAg)

This is an increasingly common pattern, but one that may sound outlandish to older readers unused to it.

---

Lastly, there seems to be no reason to think about any of this in terms of passives.

Comment: It was planned to ... ? It was chosen to ... ? It was opted to ... ? It was intended to ... ? It was meant to ... ?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I fail to understand what question your comment is asking. It was important for you to be more explicit here, as you have thoroughly confused me.

Comment: Are passives **like** "it was decided / **planned** to do" correct?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I fail to recognize why being “passive” could be thought to matter at all: this is just like any other impersonal expression like *It’s important/unlikely/... to INF-VERB*. // While I’m not here to pass moral judgement, certainly [*it was planned to...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+was+planned+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) is perfectly commonplace in present-day English, given that we’re well past celebrating its initial appearance’s quasquicentennial in our corpora. :)

Comment: But 'It was decided to leave early', by itself, apart from the context, does not tell us who is to leave early. It could be, as you assume, everyone, but it could be only those who participated in the decision making, or those who were referred to in the preceding sentence. I think that this is what worries the OP. The formulations with *that* and *for* avoid that problem. Admittedly, this theoretical problem is rarely going to amount to a real-life problem, because in real life the context will almost always make it clear who is to leave early.

Comment: @jsw29 To me that's more of a semantic concern than a syntactic one. I hope the asker elaborates. I can find no grammatical issue with corpus examples such as *It was decided that it was not advisable at this time to re-district the continent.* I don't know why, **syntactically**, it would need any extra subjects there saying "who" isn't to re-district the continent, etc.

Comment: @tchrist Impersonal passives are highly restricted. They only apply reporting verbs. So we are talking about 30ish verbs here. They fall into maybe six categories as far as the constructions they select, And those categories seem to matter here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't follow you. Are you saying that "It was chosen to ... It was opted to ... It was intended to " are clefts".

Comment: Are the colligations 'It was chosen to use one of the unassigned scope values' / 'It was opted to use one of the unassigned scope values' / 'It was intended to use one of the unassigned scope values' ... [and other V-eds]  acceptable, 'It was decided to use one of the unassigned scope values' obviously being idiomatic/grammatical?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth They are extraposition constructions, not clefts.  Clefts have the backgrounded element expressed in a relative clause.

Answer (score 0):

> It was decided...
>
> They decided...
>
> The decision was ...
>
> It was the decision...
>
> It was their decision...

could all be complemented by either of these clauses:

> ,,, to paint the house blue.
>
> ... (that) the house was to be painted blue.

P.S. With respect to your second verb, **planned**.

> It was planned ...
>
> They planned ...
>
> The plan was
>
> It was their plan ...

could all be complemented by

> ... to paint the house blue.

See [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20was%20planned%20to%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=c5fb69bdefab0649&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn09mnQ4Kuc50CbXf0LCu6rUp2G7xQg:1708448732435&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim6sC-s7qEAxUMEVkFHQbEDoUQ0pQJKAV6BAgGEAg&biw=1366&bih=681&dpr=1) for "It was planned to ..."

And if the speaker understands the verb "plan" to mean "to consider circumstances and alternatives and after such consideration to **intend** a particular course of action",  and understands that meaning to transfer over to the noun "plan", then such a speaker might well complement all of the above with

> ... that the house was to be painted blue.

"To plan that..." might sound marginal to some speakers, but that construction has [certainly been used by many a speaker](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22planned%20that%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=c5fb69bdefab0649&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn08ZBn_JzE-eBFI2jWU23brUOvzUZA:1708448431261&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK2vKusrqEAxXSrokEHQkkCsEQ0pQJKAV6BAgDEAg&biw=1366&bih=681&dpr=1).

Comment: Also “…that the house be painted blue”?

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Yes, that works as well, with the exception that "They decided that the house be painted blue" sounds a tad marginal to me -- unless the context is emphasizing that it was *their* decision to paint the house blue, not the speaker's, or that of some third party.  Such a sentence could be paraphrased "It was *they* who decided that the house be painted blue".

Comment: *Decide* is not one of our verbs that attracts the subjunctive. Compare *They demanded that the house be painted blue* and *\*They decided that the house be painted blue.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat:  I think it depends on the semantic context.  If, in context, **decide** means "to have the final say" on something, then the subjunctive passes muster. ("It was the boss's decision that the product be marketed in that way. We couldn't change his mind.")

Comment: I don’t see a verb *decide* there.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: "The boss decided that the product be marketed in that manner. He had final say and we couldn't change his mind."

Comment: Here it is in the active voice: ? *The boss decided that he market the product in that manner.* That sounds marginal at best.

Comment: It was the boss who decided that the company market the product in that manner.

Comment: ? *It was Mary who decided he eat pie.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat As I said, it is the *semantic* context, the meaning of the verb, that licenses the subjunctive, like when the meaning of **decided** is close to "insisted" or "had final say (despite objections)".  That licensing context is much more *apparent* with "It was the boss who decided that the company market the product in that manner" than it is with "It was Mary who decided that he eat pie."  But change that to "It was that bossy Mary who decided that he have the pie when what he wanted was some chocolate cake" and things are different.

Comment: @TinfoilHat But as I also said, this sounded marginal to me, and different speakers will have different senses of the degree of un/grammaticality of the marginal.

Comment: OP asks about 'it was planned to' and ([structures] like ...) similar expressions with other verbs. 'It was chosen to / voted to / opted to ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  OP mentions the word "planned" once (in the title) but every example given uses **decide**.    Where is that question you've quoted?

Comment: It is infelicitous to claim that 'Are passives like "it was decided / planned to do" correct?' doesn't refer to other similar constructions (and expressly so in the case of 'planned'). And the first two words of the body are '1

Such structures'. OP then particularises, but doesn't retract the generalised question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Felicitousness was not my goal. But  I will address **planned** with a  P.S. though my answer will be much the same. It will depend on the semantics.

Answer (score -1):

The answer may depend on the context. If the passive form of *it was decided* was unavoidable, because we really have no idea where the decision came from, then we also have no idea who is to withhold the payment, and the rest of the sentence should reflect by taking the passive form too: *the payment should be withheld*. (Whether having *to withhold the payment* in such a case would be a mistake or merely a stylistic infelicity is debatable.)

If, however, the context makes it clear who made the decision, so that, in writing and reading *it was decided*, in spite of its passive form, one clearly has in mind the thought that some definite, previously mentioned, so-and-so decided it, then *to withhold the payment* will sound natural, because it will be immediately understood as being about the same so-and-so's withholding the payment. (Arguing, in such a case, that *to withhold the payment* is incorrect will likely come across as pedantic.)

Comment: I was unable to discern why the asker was so concerned about this being in "passive voice". I don't think that matters at all.

Comment: @tchrist, my interpretation of the question is that the OP is primarily concerned about there being 'no subject' here, by which I take it that the OP meant, not that there is no grammatical subject of the sentence as a whole (as you point out, the subject it is *it*), but that  the sentence (considered apart from the context) does not tell us who is to do the withholding. I think that the OP would not be troubled at all by the third group of cases in your answer (the ones with *for*) because they make it explicit who is to do the action specified in the second part of the sentence.

Comment: I don't see why using "It was decided to withhold the payment" is wrong, and you don't offer any evidence (either based on authority or usage) - you seem to equivocate over whether it's wrong, infelicitous, or something only a pedant would object to. Would you object to an intransitive verb or a copula, such as "It was selected to taste good" or "It was made to be fast" or "It was decided to surrender at the earliest opportunity"?

Comment: @StuartF, 'It was made to be fast' is different from the OP's case because what is to be fast is the very same 'it' that is referred to at the beginning of the sentence. See the comment below the question by Mr Sweet, who 'hears' the OP's concerns the same way as I do.

Comment: According to Collins Cobuild English Grammar, which is corpus-based, 
"The passive form of reporting verbs is often used in an impersonal 'it' structure, when it is clear *whose words or thoughts you are giving* or when you are giving the words or thoughts of people in general. Such passives are followed by 'that'-clause" 

E.g. *It was agreed that* he would come ..

The book provides a long list of reporting verbs that can be used in this way, which includes 'decide' but not 'plan'.

Comment: Finally, the question whether correctness should be judged by referring to grammatical rules or actual usage is also a matter for debate. The fact that a particular struture is used does not automatically mean it is necessarily correct in the light of how the system of English works.

Comment: @StuartF. As pointed out by jsw29, my doubts result from the fact that the initial impersonal "it" cannot be interpreted as the subject which the verb "withhold" refers back to. For this reason the example: "*It was important to* withhold the payment", is a different case. It works as an impersonal sentence, since the focus is on the importance of the action, without specifying who it was important for.